# How to process a message with PossDupFlag = Y. Actually it doesn't reach the FromApp method

Tags: c#, network-protocols, fix-protocol, quickfixn

We're receiving a ResendRequest message from our acceptor, but the messages that are coming with PossDupFlag = Y, aren't being processed.

We've seen that in quickfixn validates it in the method "void DoPossUp(Message msg)" on Session class, but we don't know how quickfixn manage this message if it hasn't being processed before and needs to be processed again to ensure the good data quality.

We've deleted the files where body and headers are stored but messages aren't processed.

What's the right behaviour and how we can test a right escenario in a data loss scenario?

Comment: What's in your message log?  Is your engine rejecting it at the transport layer?

Comment: if *you* receive the Inbound FIX.ResendRequest(35=2) from the acceptor end, *you* will be the one that is expected to (re)send outbound FIX.Messages with PossDupFlag(43)=Y, not the other way around. Likely the only processing that you may do is to "skip" the resending on some messages, depending of your business logic context...